# ¿Cómo mostrar en phpexcel otras filas?

Tags: php, phpexcel

```
require_once('./u/excel/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
require_once('./u/excel/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php');
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007(); 
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("./u/precios.xlsx"); 
$objFecha = new PHPExcel_Shared_Date();

$pagexcel=0;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($pagexcel);
$FilasCantidadNUMEROS = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow(); 
$ColumnasCantidadLETRAS = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn();
$contenidoparabusquedavanzada=array();

echo '<table width="100%;" class="convgconsdfconttab listadecatalogocompleta listvgcatcom listvgcatcomact '.(  ($_GET['s']=='buscar')?('dn'):('')  ).'">';
for ($row = 1; $row <= $FilasCantidadNUMEROS; $row++) {
echo '<tr class="numnom">';
echo '<td width="20%" class="num somin">'.$row.'</td>';
echo '<td class="nom somin">'.$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow('A', $row)->getValue().'</td>';
echo '<td class="nom somin">'.$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow('B', $row)->getValue().'</td>';
echo '<td class="nom somin">'.$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow('C', $row)->getValue().'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
$contenidoparabusquedavanzada[]=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow('A', $row)->getValue();
} echo '</table>';
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo puedo hacer para que me muestre los resultados correspondientes de las filas? tiene bien definidas las columnas A B C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

logre extraer el dato exacto con

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.$row)->getValue()
```

[Fuente](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/accessing-cells/)